RewriteRule issue after 5th rule
I am stuck in a viard issue.
I have the below set of RewriteRule configured in httpd.conf for one of my domain.
----
<Directory "/var/www/html/test/">
    
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/1.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
RewriteRule le/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/2.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
RewriteRule lo/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/3.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
RewriteRule l/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/4.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
RewriteRule w/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/5.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
RewriteRule s/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/6.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
RewriteRule n/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/7.php?d=$1 [L,NC]
    
require all granted

</Directory>

----

The rule after the 5th rule is not working in the above rule set.
In my case, the rules below are not working.
RewriteRule s/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/6.php?d=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule n/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ short/7.php?d=$1 [L,NC]

Both these rules give the same output as the 5th rule.
I have shuffled the rules up and down still any rules after 5th rule are not working as expected.
I don't know what I am doing wrong or missing anything, any help will be highly appreciated.
Please advise.

When in doubt - enable a bit of rewrite logging, and then check what exactly is happening internally.

Bit weird that all of your patterns except the first one, are not anchored to the beginning of the test subject, I doubt that is deliberate?

It might also help to add a few example request URLs to the question. And what result you would expect for each of those.
